# Insect Identification needed

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found this sitting on my window, could not understand what it is. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Where did you find it?

Comment: Size and location would help a lot!

Comment: size - 3 inches max and location is Rajarhat. It can fly. Is their any moth that comes similer? Its my guess though.

Comment: It is a moth, maybe [Miresa clarissa](http://www.americaninsects.net/lep/miresa-clarissa.html) but not sure, so not an answer.

Comment: @anongoodnurce Thanks. I checked several other pics of this insect and the pic I clicked. Its almost looked the same and most probably the ans you have provided is correct.